# PHP. Парсинг. Нажатие на кнопку(Отправка формы)

Tags: php, javascript, парсер, form

Пишу парсер для одного сайта. Использую библиеотеку

> simple_html_dom

Написал такой код:

```
<?php
  require "simple_html_dom.php";
  /* Получаем документ, находим необходимые элелементы для авторизации и
      устанавливаем им значения логина и пароля.
  */
  $html = file_get_html('http://sb.ua/?id=2&cat=1');

  foreach($html->find('input[name=login]') as $login)
    $login->value = 'k@l.ru';
  foreach($html->find('input[name=pass]') as $login)
    $login->value = '15r';
  // проверяем установлено ли значение
  foreach($html->find('input[name=login]') as $element)
    echo $element->value . '<br>';

    foreach($html->find('input[name=pass]') as $element)
      echo $element->value . '<br>';
 ?>
```

Нужно форму, элементам которой установлены значения для авторизации, отправить для обработки на их сервер. После, нужно получить вернувшийся документ, для дальнейшего парсинга.

П.С. ссылка на страницу с библиотекой [тут.](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Если есть варианты реализации этого на JavaScript, с удовольствием посмотрю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такого сложного способа авторизации я ещё не видел. Хотя видел вроде. Матчасть поучили бы что ли...
Авторизация строится передачей POST запроса, который является, в общем-то, строкой (HTTP1), DOM нужен браузеру для визуализации и логического отделения элементов, для сервера этого не нужно, подобные библиотеки используются чтобы распарсить значения из уже имеющихся HTML документов.

Учитывая это, можно просто сделать так:

```
$context = stream_context_create([
    'http' => [
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' . PHP_EOL,
        'content' => 'login={Your login}&pass={Your password}&remember=0', // Хм, фигурные скобки нужно убрать, тут они для наглядности, а то вдруг...
    ],
]);

file_get_contents('http://sborka.ua/inc/login.php', false, $context)
```

Comment: Разобрался в вашем коде, изучил использованные в нем функции, спасибо. Но авторизация не проходит. Возвращается контент начальной страницы...

Comment: @DenisOleshchenko, тут уже надо копать на месте - может заголовок особый нужен, может ещё что.